# Two aurelia apps on same page binding twice

Tags: webpack, aurelia

I am using Webpack 3 to bundle two separate Aurelia apps on the same page.

One is the main body of the application and uses the standard `setRoot` method:

```
export function configure(aurelia) {
    aurelia.use
        .standardConfiguration()
        .feature(PLATFORM.moduleName('resources/index'));

    aurelia.start().then(a => {
        aurelia.setRoot(PLATFORM.moduleName('shells/app'),
        document.getElementById('AppBodyContainer'));
    });
}
```

The other uses the enhance method on an old MVC view

```
const enhanceNode = (app, node, bindingContext = null) => {
    const engine = app.container.get(TemplatingEngine);
    const component = engine.enhance({
        container: app.container,
        element: node,
        resources: app.resources,
        bindingContext: bindingContext
    });
    component.attached();
};

export function configure(aurelia) {
    aurelia.use
        .standardConfiguration()
        .feature(PLATFORM.moduleName('resources/index'));

    aurelia.start().then(a => {
        enhanceNode(a, document.getElementById('HeaderContainer'));
    });
}
```

Both are standalone aurelia apps, and both use the webpack `AureliaPlugin`

```
new AureliaPlugin({
    aureliaApp: 'header-app'
}),
```

The problem is that whenever both are on the same page, the separate version of `aurelia-binding` are interfering with each other, which means that anything bound through `click.delegate` is fired twice on click.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You're not doing anything wrong, this is something specific to `click.delegate`. Aurelia puts a shared event listener on the `body` tag that the `delegate` events bubble up to, so there will be two listeners per event because of this.

You could use `click.trigger` which does not use event delegation, but instead puts the listener directly on the element (make sure to cancel the bubble by returning `false` from your handler).

Comment: The main app has been around for some time and has 198 instances of click.delegate, so changing them all was not really reasonable.  However I was able to fix the issue by changing just the ones in the new app (the one using the `enhance` feature)